# How should i chain lapply sequences idiomatically in R?

Tags: r

I have just written a function that uses  a serie of lapply calls to transform data, like this:

```
somefun <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  filenames <- sprintf("%03d.csv", id)
  filenames <- paste(directory, filenames, sep="/")
  ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
  cdf <- lapply(ldf,complete.cases)
  icdf <- lapply(cdf,as.numeric)
  sicdf <- lapply(cdf,sum)
  result <- cbind(id,sicdf)
  result
}
```

Is there a better way to write this sequence of `lapplys` in R?

Answer (score 6):

It's not always the best approach, but my absolutely favorite way to simplify a whole series of calls like that is to use the `magrittr` package.

It essentially creates a *pipe* that sort of forwards arguments from one command to another.  It does wonders for long chains or sequences of calls like this.  The period/dot can be used to specify where the values from the previous stage are 'piped.'

Try something like this:

```
library(magrittr) # use install.packages("magrittr") if needed

sprintf("%03d.csv", id) %>%
    paste(directory, filenames, sep="/") %>%
    lapply(read.csv) %>%
    lapply(complete.cases) %>%
    lapply(as.numeric) %>%
    lapply(sum) %>%
    cbind(id, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Reduce` strategy. Here's some sample data

```
xx<-matrix(runif(25), nrow=5)
xx[2,3]<-NA
write.table(xx, "num.txt")
```

Then you could run

```
trans<-list(
    read.table,
    function(x) x[complete.cases(x),],
    colSums
)

Reduce(lapply, trans, list("num.txt"))
```

Note that some of those functions you are lapply-ing might not work the way you would like. For example `complete.cases` doesn't really subset at all, do you can see how i used it in my list of transformations. And same goes for `as.numeric` and `sum`.

Comment: This looks better than the `magrittr` option although they may not be equivalent. The `magrittr` answer essentially just uses the pipe which is great for readability but not really any different than OP's.