# R coding question pertaining to multiple functions in lapply

Tags: r

I would like to add more functions under the original lapply function.

original code

```
result <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:100)), function(x) transform(x, 
             food = factor(food, level=c("a","b"), labels=c("apple","banana"))))
```

functions I want to add under the original code.

```
function(x) transform(x, na.omit(x)),
function(x) transform(x, Y_N = factor(Y_N, level=c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))),
function(x) transform(x, as.Date(df1$x))
```

lapply is very new to me so I couldn't be able to add up more functions under the original function.

I thought I could do it like below but it won't work :'(

```
result <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:100)), function(x) transform(x, 
             food = factor(food, level=c("a","b"), labels=c("apple","banana"))),
function(x) transform(x, na.omit(x)),
function(x) transform(x, Y_N = factor(Y_N, level=c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))),
function(x) transform(x, as.Date(df1$x)))
```

Comment: For reference, this looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196618/how-should-i-chain-lapply-sequences-idiomatically-in-r) on how to chain multiple lapply calls as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them in the same `transform` function :

```
result <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:100)), function(x) 
  transform(na.omit(x), 
            food = factor(food, level=c("a","b"), labels=c("apple","banana")), 
            Y_N = factor(Y_N, level=c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes")), 
             x =   as.Date(x)))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, it worked beautifully! Btw would it be fine with you if I ask another question regarding coding in R? I want to loop the following df1, ... df100 but can't write a code with lapply :'( Just want to show summary of df1, to df100 on console.

summary(df1  %>%  select(food) %>% group_by(food))
same for df2, ... df100

Comment: You can try `lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:100)), function(x) summary(x$food))`